# Cant control drag a reference object to the ViewController in Xcode 9.2 (9C40b) iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

How to a create an outlet for an iOS control on the storyboard that is connected to my swift ViewController code?

All the tutorials for iOS development show that you can control drag a UI element to your ViewContoller swift code for an outlet. However it never works for me, it shows the blue line from the storyboard, but on the drop it never brings up the dialog to add a new outlet.

Creating a new Action drag and drop works just fine for buttons. I have seen many ask this question and there seems to be no definite answer.

Is there something different with iOS projects?

I tried to set the View Controller custom class to my specific ViewController class, and then I can drag and drop a new outlet. However the project fails to compile.

```
LaunchScreen.storyboard: error: Illegal Configuration: Launch screens may not set custom classnames
```

I seem to be missing something here, but all the tutorials I watch/read (none seem to cover Xcode 9 or swift 4) all show this behavior as being the normal way to create an outlet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch screens are not able to have outlets attached to them. They are static. If you'd like to have a "launch screen" that you can manipulate, duplicate your launch screen layout into an initial view controller and do what you like there.

Comment: Yes, very important aspect I seemed to have missed. Thank you very much.

Comment: I was unaware of this: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/launch-screen/

Comment: @RonaldoNascimento that is a good guideline to follow but apps rarely do. If you feel strongly about having a splash screen you can implement one. It won’t be a cert blocker.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because you are connecting it from the `LaunchScreen.xib` instead of the `main.storyboard` files.

Comment: As far as I can tell there are no XIB files in this project. I am connecting from the LaunchScreen.storyboard file.

Comment: Ah, so that's whats happening sir I suggest you start a new project as you cannot connect UI elements from a LaunchScreen.storyboard .

Comment: Or you can go to File>New>File> storyboard and name it main.storyboard